# May the gabbai use a disabled person for shat"z over a non-disabled one?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, chazzan-prayer-leader, handicap-disabled-impair

In a few previous questions, I mentioned that I sometimes daven in a nursing home minyan.

This past Shabbat, the gabbai asked someone who is confined to a wheelchair to daven Musaph. There were other non-disabled people in the shul. I assume that since this person was a guest, the gabbai wanted to give him the honor.

The prayer is called *Amidah* because one **should** stand for it, if he can. Is a shul allowed to use someone who can't stand for *amidah* as a shat"z if there are others who can stand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Jerusalem-based kollel Eretz Hemda has a responsa on this very topic ([here](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=644&article=2384)). Their conclusion is that

> If [a person is] permanently (or for a long time) in need of a
>   wheelchair, people should get used to including them in all activities
>   that make them feel included in a normal life, as their personalities
>   demand and halacha allows. **They should be allowed to be chazanim under
>   these circumstances**, certainly, as is almost always the case, when we
>   are talking about one who is not a full-time chazan (or was previously
>   appointed as chazan).

This appears particularly appropriate in a retirement house context where we know, from your other questions, that a number of patients have health issues. See [the original](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=644&article=2384) for the full details and their [*tshuva* in Hebrew](https://www.sefaria.org/B'Mareh_HaBazak_Volume_VII.3?lang=bi) in B'Mareh Habazak VII:3.